# How can I run at boot or autostart an app with GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, raspbian

I have a python script with a GUI that was designed with qt5, the script runs fine whenever I run it through the terminal or Thonny IDE. But no matter how much I tried, after trying many guides, videos, Chatgpt sessions I couldn't make it run on boot or AutoStart after boot to the Raspbian..

Is there a way to just create a desktop shortcut to run the application directly?

After I gave up I built a distributable file using pyinstaller `--onefile your_script.py`  and tried the same but with no success!.

Now at the end I am satisfied of having my application running by double clicking it's icon from the desktop which is as well not working as:

- the exe file should be in the same folder of the python scripts and other files.
- every time I double click it, it asks "Execute, execute in terminal, cancel".

Comment: Are you using Raspbian or Raspberry Pi OS? Which version?

Comment: I am using Raspbian ..

Comment: This still does not answer which version... Try 'cat /etc/os-release'

Comment: @maciek 
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)" NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)" VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE-debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/" SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums BUG REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs